# What is equivalent of RequestDispatcher#forward() Of Java in PHP?

Tags: php

RequestDispatcher basically dispatches a request to some other resource i.e it doesn't do a redirect but simply forwards the page to some page(resource). Thus browser's history etc is not updated and the parameters that are available in `request` are still available on another page since we are not creating a new request using redirect.

What is equivalent of this in PHP? And also which function is used to redirect a page?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent.

[`include`](http://php.net/include) and family are similar, but differ in several aspects:

- The current state of the script is kept (any global variables, function and class definition, etc.)
- A file path must be given

Probably the most similar thing is an internal Apache subrequest (see [`virtual`](http://php.net/virtual)), but that has nothing to do with PHP itself. When PHP is invoked, the request has already been "dispatched". Of course, you can, if you want, do a virtual "request dispatch logic"  with PHP, which means sending all the requests to some initial script that then decides what to include/execute. This is what several frameworks do.

To redirect a page, you manually send a header:

```
header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} $code"); //code can be 301, 302, 303, 307
header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Concepts Redirect and Forward like in Java, can be achievable in PHP too.

Redirect (URL in address bar changes  ) --  `header("Location: redirect.php");`

Forward  (URL unchanged at address bar) --  `include forward.php ;`

I hope, Its manageable with this & other programming logics known.